# Can you cancel the stackoverflow exception in the following code?

Tags: programming-puzzle, c#

The following code will produce a run-time error, `stackoverflow` exception.

```csharp
class Foo
{
    //static Foo foo = new Foo(); // you are not allowed using this approach
    //static readonly Foo foo = new Foo(); // you are not allowed using this approach
    Foo foo = new Foo();
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Foo();
    }
}
```

The objective is to cancel the exception without

- removing, modifying or commenting out the existing code,
- using the approaches mentioned (and their variants in access modifiers, `public`, `private`, etc) as the given comments,
- using `try-catch-finally` or its variants,
- using attributes,
- using compilation condition,

You are only allowed to add your own code inside the `Foo` class. How do you cancel the exception at run-time?

Comment: It would be best to tag this question as either [tag:popularity-contest] or [tag:code-golf] so it's clear how you will objectively declare a winner.

Comment: I probably will add more rules if your ideas are too trivial. Sorry for this inconvenience.

Comment: Pulling the rug out like that may be considered rude. It's best to think your question through thoroughly before asking the internet to spend effort on it. :-)

Comment: This is a [tag:popularity-contest] yet the accepted answer has few votes. You should accept the highest-voted answer (see [tag:popularity-contest])

Comment: @Quincunx: I changed the tag.

Comment: You need winning criterion (?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Never wrote C# before, does this work ?

```cs
class Foo
{
    Foo fooExit = exitMe();
    //static Foo foo = new Foo(); // you are not allowed using this approach
    //static readonly Foo foo = new Foo(); // you are not allowed using this approach
    Foo foo = new Foo();

    static Foo exitMe()
    {
        System.Environment.Exit(0);
        return null;
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Foo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the rules forbid "using attributes".

Comment: @Victor: The code above does not contain any attributes.

Comment: @StiffJokes Interesting. I am from Java and never programmed in C#. In Java the `Foo fooExit = exitMe();` would be a declaration of an attribute called `fooExit`. I.E. For me attribute and field were synonyms. Googling this, it looks like that in C# attributes are more-or-less what in java are called annotations. Thank you, did not knew this!

Comment: I changed the tag just for attracting more creative method. :-)

Comment: The winner might be different from the accepted  answer. It does not matter for me.

Comment: `foo` must be declared after `fooExit` to make the trick work.

Comment: As I see it, this does not cancel the exception but exit the program, before it is thrown. Does that really count?

Answer (score 31):

Here, another try:

```cs
class Foo
{
    //static Foo foo = new Foo(); // you are not allowed using this approach
    //static readonly Foo foo = new Foo(); // you are not allowed using this approach
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    MWAHAHAHA, THIS LINE GIVES A COMPILE ERROR! NO STACKOVERFLOW EXCEPTION ANYMORE! LOL
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Foo();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is really funny, really.

Comment: That's what I was gonna do...

Answer (score 25):

How about this?

```cs
class Foo
{
    //static Foo foo = new Foo(); // you are not allowed using this approach
    //static readonly Foo foo = new Foo(); // you are not allowed using this approach
    String str = @"
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    ";
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Foo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

```cs
class Foo
{
    public class Bar
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Foo();
    }
}
```

I don't have a C# compiler at hand, but I suspect this might work. The idea is to put the definition in a nested class, such that `foo` would only be assigned if an instance of `Bar` is created. Now, the problem is that (I believe) the nested class needs to be `public`. I don't know if this is a rule violation, i.e. that the rule applies to any use of an access modifier, or only if applied to `foo`. (Could someone who can compile C# please try this with and without the `public`?)

Comment: Works with and without `public`. You also could've tested this on an online compiler, e.g. ideone.

Answer (score 8):

```cs
class Foo
{
    Foo(bool recursion = false)
    {
        if (recursion)
            Foo foo = new Foo();
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Foo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

To simplify Florent's code:

```cs
class Foo
{
    Foo foo = new Foo();

    static Foo() {
        System.Environment.Exit(1);
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this actually work? Won't `Foo foo = new Foo();` be (recursively) evaluated before any constructor is executed?

Comment: @nitro2k01 No, it won't. The `static` ctor is executed before any instance member initialization.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Foo
{
    while (true);
    Foo foo = new Foo();
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Foo();
    }
}
```

Its not a bug, it's a feature!

In case that doesn't work

```
class Foo
    if(false)
        Foo foo = new Foo();
}

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Foo();
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess that stopping stack overflow from happening by making infinite loop prior to it counts. It doesn't appear to be disallowed.

Comment: @xfix Indeed.
Since the problematic code will never be executed, it cannot cause a lockup.
Aka: You cannot lock me up because I'll lock me up first :-P

Comment: I can't see how that would compile in C#. I'm getting a `Invalid token 'while' in class, struct, or interface member declaration` compiler error with your code.

Comment: @Mark - Hmmm, seems a little passive-aggressive... ;) I like it.

Comment: @simon It's called c-SHARP, because its not for the soft-hearted :-P

Answer (score 3):

The Answer is:

```
class Foo
{
    //static Foo foo = new Foo(); // you are not allowed using this approach
    //static readonly Foo foo = new Foo(); // you are not allowed using this approach

    public void Method()
    {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Foo();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note: The rules changed since I posted this.**

That is it:

```cs
class Foo
{
    //static Foo foo = new Foo(); // you are not allowed using this approach
    //static readonly Foo foo = new Foo(); // you are not allowed using this approach
    Foo foo = null; // Removing code != modifying.
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Foo();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is almost funny, just almost. :-)

Comment: Your trivial code can actually be simplified as `Foo foo;` to make it almost funnier.

Comment: @StiffJokes In this case, you could argue that I was deleting code, against the rules (as they were at that time).

Answer (score 0):

```
class Foo
{
    //static Foo foo = new Foo(); // you are not allowed using this approach
    //static readonly Foo foo = new Foo(); // you are not allowed using this approach
    Foo foo = true?null: new Foo();
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Foo();
    }
}
```